# How to extimate the standard deviation of a prediction for a linear model using bootstrap in R

Tags: r

I have a training data set Y= 1,2,3,4,5 and X= 1,2,2,3,4. I want to estimate the standard deviation of the prediction when X=3. How do I do that in R. Below the code I have completed but I'm not sure about my procedure.

```
y <- c(1,2,3,4,5) #input predictor
x <- c(1,2,2,3,4) #input response
data.set <- data.frame(x,y) #create data frame for x, y
boot.fn <- function(data, index)
{
  linreg <- lm(y~x, data = data, subset=index)
  prediction <- predict.lm(linreg, data.frame(x=c(3)))
  return(prediction)
}
boot(data.set, boot.fn, R=1200)
```

Answer (score -1):

The procedure above is right. When applying bootstrap the standard error of the estimation is the standard deviation of the estimate.